# Duplicate interface definition for class "GADBannerview" after start using Cocoapods

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I was manually implementing Google Admob SDK on one of my xCode Projects, the project was really old (Made in xCode 5.0), so when i openned the project today (xCode 7.0) i got plenty of errors many of them related to Admob SDK, i figure that i could solve the problem by removing Admob SDK, and them install it Again using COCOA PODS, but after doing that i'm getting the error:

**duplicate interface definition for class "GADBannerView"**

I already Cleaned the project, and deleted the Derived Data Folder, and i still getting this error, what else could i possible do?

Thanks in advance for any help!